# double click on python file to open but cmd hide automatic in work in background processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I wanted to hide and unhide cmd in my program when user open it i was success but then when i made exe file and open it cmd hide and never unhide so i try on other project and double click on it cmd opened but so fast hide ,,, i do not know why it happend but it is so bad...

i use these code to hide and unhide but in other program i did not use , cmd agian hide for all program

```
import win32com.client 
import win32con
import win32gui
from win32con import SW_HIDE
from win32con import SW_SHOWNORMAL
import time

def hidden():
    pid = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    win32gui.ShowWindow(pid , SW_HIDE)
def unhide():
    hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_SHOWNA)

hidden()
time.sleep(6)

unhide()
```

Comment: If it's hidden it cannot be the foreground window. You need to store the hWnd (not PID).

Comment: how change my code to work??

Comment: You need to store win32gui.GetForegroundWindow() which returns the window's hWnd.

Comment: dear i can not understand your meaning may u write correct code for me

Comment: Don't call me dear as you are not my wife. Save the hWnd from your first call to GetForegroundWindow. Then use it to unhide.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow